# Hindi jQuery Quiz not showing correct answer

Tags: jquery

I have created a quiz in blogger using jquery but output shows all answers incorrect when I select the correct answer.

Code to create quiz

```
<div class="faqbox">
<div id="quiz1"></div></div>

<script src='https://storage.googleapis.com/chydlx/plugins/dlx-quiz/js/main.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

$("#quiz1").dlxQuiz({
quizData: {
    questions: [
        {
            q:"लेख 'मैं नास्तिक क्यों हूँ।' लिखा गया था",
            a:"भगत सिंह द्वारा",
            options: ["चन्द्र शेखर आजाद द्वारा","रासबिहारी बोस द्वारा","भगत सिंह द्वारा","सुभाष चन्द्र बोस द्वारा"]
        },

        {
            q:"विश्व प्रसिद्ध मीसॉन (माइसॉन) मंदिर समूह दक्षिण पूर्व एशिया के किस प्राचीन राज्य की धरोहर है?",
            a:"चंपा",
            options: ["चंपा","फूनान","श्रीविजय","माताराम"]
        }

    ]
}
});
```

Result:

Quiz output:

[image]